# Counting Values in R Vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a large vector of percentages (0-100) and I am trying to count how many of them are in 
specific 20% buckets (<20, 20-40, 40-60,60-80,80-100). The vector has length 129605 and there are no 
NA values. Here's my code:

```
x<-c(0,0,0,0,0)
for(i in 1: length(mail_return))
{
    if (mail_return[i]<=20)
    {
        x[1] = x[1] + 1
    }
    if (mail_return[i]>20 && mail_return[i]<=40)
    {
        x[2] = x[2] + 1
    }
    if (mail_return[i]>40 && mail_return[i]<=60)
    {
        x[3] = x[3] + 1
    }
    if (mail_return[i]>60 && mail_return[i]<=80)
    {
        x[4] = x[4] + 1
    }
    else
    {   
        x[5] = x[5] + 1
    }
}
```

But `sum(x)` is giving me length 133171. Shouldn't it be the length of the vector, 129605? What's wrong?

Comment: Very shortly, you're going to want to marry the functions `cut` and `table`.

Comment: Also, take a look at `ifelse`.

Comment: Why can't you all just elaborate?

Comment: @GTyler - Because this sort of question has been answered several times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570293/r-adding-column-which-contains-bin-value-of-another-column  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746544/r-cut-by-defined-interval S.O. is not a replacement for research.

Comment: Why are the negative votes? I didn't know it was the intervals that went wrong. I thought it was something else.

Comment: Speaking only for myself: when provided two helpful pointers to some very useful functions, you responded with a rude and demanding comment, rather than simply reading the documentation.

Comment: I think `GTyler` has a point. `joran`, the documentation is good to refer him to, but I think an explanation is in order here, because he went to good lengths to try to solve this himself, and his APPROACH is clearly off (using `for` &`if` for simple tasks) - so he deserves a nod in the right direction.

Comment: @user1717913 Perhaps I didn't have time to write a full answer and was trying to be as helpful as I could? Rather than a "Thanks!" I get a whiny comment that I didn't do more. I don't think it's unreasonable to expect better behavior from question askers.

Comment: I see your point. I do understand though, that seeing nothing but short, nonspecific responses would be frustrating, because it would appear as though people felt they had answered you.

Comment: @joran You'll get a "Thanks!" when you give a comprehensive response. As for being demanding, I want more than just pointers which may lead to more hair-pulling for me (and I don't have much hair!). By the time you typed up that comment, you can probably come up with a decent response. Thank you and good day to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like `findInterval` for these sorts of tasks:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,20,21,22,40,41,42,60,61,62,80,81,82)
table(findInterval(x,c(0,20,40,60,80)))


1 2 3 4 5 
3 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: I would've used `table(cut(x, breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80,100)))`, but I like the cleaner output of `findInterval` - thanks `latemail`! 

As a side note, `GTyler`, although you don't need the `&` operator here, `&&` is not the same in R as it is in other languages - it takes only the FIRST object in a vector - probably the reason for your error. I've never encountered a situation where `&` is not preferred.

Comment: @user1717913: `&&` is almost always preferred in `if` statements.  From `?"&&"`: "The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in ‘if’ clauses."

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I must have misunderstood when I first learned this. Is `cond1 && cond2` identical to `all(cond1 & cond2)`? (in result and/or speed)?

Comment: @user1717913: No, the second one evaluates more than the first element of `cond1` and `cond2`, whereas `&&` only evaluates the first element of each.

Answer (score 2):

The **reason for the bad count** is that
 x[5] effectively counts every occurrence which doesn't satisfy the condition
 `mail_return[i]>60 && mail_return[i]<=80`,
i.e. counting items that are > 80 (as you would expect), but also counting anew items that are <= 60 (outch! that the bug!).

You can replace...

```
if (mail_return[i]>60 && mail_return[i]<=80)
{
    x[4] = x[4] + 1
}
else
{   
    x[5] = x[5] + 1
}
```

by...

```
if (mail_return[i]>60 && mail_return[i]<=80)
{
    x[4] = x[4] + 1
}

if (mail_return[i] >80)
{   
    x[5] = x[5] + 1
}
```

...to fix things.

But as hinted in other answers, there are **better idioms to find counts** (such as `table(findInterval(...))` ) which do not require such longhand code (and which are more efficient).