# Reducing a data frame by a value range

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form

```
Age     Average   

16        1.89
17        6.88
...       ...
85        7.44
```

I'd like to reduce this data to make a boxplot of average score by decade of age (10-20, 21-30  etc). Is there a function for this?

For reference I'm accounting for 'averaging averages', it's more just to ask about this mechanism'

Comment: average of averages? mmmm doesn't sound good. It will not have any significance.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746544/r-cut-by-defined-interval), I think `cut(Age, breaks = seq(10, 90, by = 10)` would give you what you want.

Comment: @PA. I'm accounting for that, this is more to ask about the mechanism

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
aggregate(df, by = list(cut(df$Age, seq(10, 90, 10))), FUN = mean)
```

where `df` is your data frame

Comment: the user is trying to make a boxplot, this answer results in one value for each "bin" of age. why would they want that?

Comment: my understanding was that the OP wants a boxplot based on the averaged data, that can be of course easily done `boxplot(adf$Average)` where `adf` is the aggregated data frame. Whether it makes sense it is another question. But I agree that the goal may not be very clear here.

Comment: okay, I guess i interpreted the question differently...your last sentence is true

Answer (score 0):

We should use the `cut` function

```
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Age = 16:85,
                 Values = rnorm(70))
DF$AgeGroup = cut(DF$Age, breaks = seq(10, 90, by = 10))
boxplot(Values~AgeGroup, data = DF)
```

[image]

Note that I've generated some dummy data to demonstrate the mechanism.