# Defined interval in R by cut() and make a histogram plot

Tags: r, histogram, intervals, cut

I am struggling to figure it out how to use `cut()` function to define `interval` of my data of interest by `12 months`. I read this post  [R - Cut by Defined Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746544/r-cut-by-defined-interval). But it dose not help what I am looking for.

say, I have a set of data name `months` which have values less than a `year <12` months till `50 months`.

```
set.seed(50); sample(50) -> months
```

I want to use the `cut()` function to have the number of data which falls in each year including `< 12 months`.

```
> cut(months, breaks =  seq(12,50, by= 12))-> output
> output
 [1] (24,36] (12,24] <NA>    (36,48] (12,24] <NA>    (24,36] (24,36] <NA>    <NA>   
[11] (12,24] <NA>    (24,36] (36,48] (36,48] (36,48] (24,36] (12,24] (36,48] <NA>   
[21] (12,24] (36,48] (12,24] (12,24] <NA>    (12,24] (12,24] (24,36] <NA>    <NA>   
[31] (12,24] (36,48] (24,36] (36,48] <NA>    <NA>    (36,48] (12,24] (36,48] (24,36]
[41] (36,48] (12,24] (24,36] <NA>    <NA>    (24,36] <NA>    (24,36] (24,36] (36,48]
Levels: (12,24] (24,36] (36,48]

> table(output)
output
(12,24] (24,36] (36,48] 
     12      12      12
```

**Questions**

**1-** How I can get the number of data for `< 12 months` **while** I keep having the 12 months `interval`?

I tried this but dose not work!

```
> cut(months, breaks =  seq(1,12,50, by= 12))-> output
```

**2-** How I can make a `hist()` plot by this data?

Thanks,

Comment: @GGamba , Dose not work perfectly : `output
 (1,13] (13,25] (25,37] (37,49] 
     12      12      12      12` . I need to be 12 not 13!

Comment: `seq(0, 50, by = 12)`

Comment: seq(0, 50, by = 12) (sorry posted at same time as @Gamba). Also, what's a hiso() plot?

Comment: If you mean `hist()` plot, then you first have to label your cuts (label = c(1:4) for example). Then you could do hist(as.mumeric(output)). However, since all your bins are the same size, in this example, it's not very informative.

Comment: See my comment above. You first have to pass a label to your cut function (with a number of labels equal to your number of cuts). Then use the hist() function. For more info, look at the cut and hist function documentation.

Comment: `output <- cut(months, breaks =  seq(0,50, by= 12), labels = c("<12","12-24","24-35","36-50"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(50)
months <- sample(50)

output <- cut(months, breaks = seq(0,50, by= 12), labels = c("<12","12-24","24-35","36-50"))

hist(as.numeric(output))
```

You'll have to edit the axis values on the histogram manually, since they will be labeled at an interval 1-4. And as I mentioned in my comment. The histogram isn't very informative, considering all the values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_col()` will provide you with a clearer histogram since the data are already in a frequency table.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(50)
months <- sample(50)

output <- cut(months, breaks = seq(0,50, by= 12), labels = c("<12","12-24","24-35","36-50"))

table(output) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = output, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]