# Replacing numbers with a label in DF

Tags: r

I have a DF with a 'size' column with numbers. I would like to replace these numbers with small, medium or large based on the ranges small = 1:10 medium = 11:49 large = 50:200.

I have tried using

```
table$Size <- factor(table$Size,
                    levels = c(1:10),c(11:49),c(50:200),
                    labels = c("small"),c("medium"),c("large"))
```

But I understand why this doesnt work.
I have also tried using str_replace all but this also produce an error.

Is there a way to replace numbers within these ranges with the respective label?

Comment: You should use `cut`/`findInterval` instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979456/r-code-to-categorize-age-into-group-bins-breaks and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746544/cut-by-defined-interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cut()` function converts numerical variables to factors. You can supply `breaks` to tell where the cuts should happen. This replaces your attempt at `levels`. Then you apply your `labels`. You also need to specify a `right` argument - should the interval be closed on the right (or left if false).

```
set.seed(10)
x <- sample(1:200, 1000, replace = TRUE)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00   50.75  101.00  101.57  153.00  200.00 
x <- cut(x, breaks = c(0, 10, 49, 200),
         labels = c("small", "medium", "large"),
         right = TRUE)
summary(x)
 small medium  large 
    51    189    760
```

I also want to point out an issue with your code. In your line `labels = c("small"),c("medium"),c("large")`, you have the commas outside the `c()`. You should enclose all desired elements of your vector in the same `c()`:

```
 labels = c("small", "medium", "large")
```

If the commas are outside of the parentheses, R will map only `c("small")` to `labels` and then try to match `c("medium")` to the next argument of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Recode the `levels` with a list.

```
table1$Size.fac <- factor(table1$Size)

levels(table1$Size.fac) <- list("small" = 1:10,
                            "medium" = 11:49,
                            "large" = 50:200)

table1
#   Size Size.fac
# 1  156    large
# 2   17   medium
# 3  128    large
# 4    7    small
# 5   77    large
# 6  112    large
```

---

*Data:*

```
table1 <- structure(list(Size = c(156L, 17L, 128L, 7L, 77L, 112L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```